# Find group with distinct Sylow $p$-subgroups that share a normalizer

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

Here a question I thought of, but can't find an answer to

> Find two distinct Sylow $p$-subgroups (of a given $p$) $H_1$ and $H_2$ of $G$ such that $N_G(H_1) = N_G(H_2)$.

I don't know if it's actually possible, so I should qualify the question with

> If no such pair exists, show why.

Well, the easiest case would be if $H_1$ and $H_2$ were normal, however this would imply that $n_p = 1$. Hence, we'd only have one Sylow $p$-subgroup.

My intuition says that such a pair does exist, however. Of course, it's merely intuition...

Comment: This is not possible. The normalizer of a Sylow $p$- subgroup has a unique Sylow $p$-subgroup. Well, because the one it has is normal, that is $H_1\unlhd N_G(H_1)$ :-)

Comment: A bit more seriously. This argument is often seen when proving that $N_G(N_G(P))=N_G(P)$ for all Sylow subgroups $P$ of $G$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Please move your comment to an answer so that this question does not show as unanswered. Thanks.

Comment: @StephenMeskin James already gave that as an answer (obviously he arrived at it independently from me), but then deleted his answer. I could use my powervote undelete, but I'm a bit hesitant to do that against his wish.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen If you won't post the answer, I will as a community wiki.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to a comment by @JyrkiLahtonen and others:
"This is not possible. The normalizer of a Sylow $p$- subgroup has a unique Sylow $p$-subgroup. Well, because the one it has is normal, that is $H_1⊴N_G(H_1)$."